# Can't install packages using pip in a Conda environment

Tags: pip, package, conda

Can't install packages using pip in a Conda environment.
I am getting timeout when trying to pip install.
when trying to extend the timeout I'm getting a protocol error.

when trying to telnet directly from cli to pypi.org there is no problem.
there are no fw rule on my laptop or a proxy in use.
couldn't find any special pip configuration file on my filesystem.

what am i missing?

```
(base) [liran@localhost ~]$ pip3 install django
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/django/

(base) [liran@localhost ~]$ pip3 --default-timeout=1000 install django
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/django/

(base) [liran@localhost ~]$ telnet pypi.org 443
Trying 2a04:4e42::223...
Connected to pypi.org.
Escape character is '^]'.

(base) [liran@localhost ~]$ sudo iptables --list
[sudo] password for liran: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             localhost           
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16      
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12       

Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

(base) [liran@localhost ~]$ sudo iptables --list-rules
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-e6c6ca45026f -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-e6c6ca45026f -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-e6c6ca45026f ! -o br-e6c6ca45026f -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-e6c6ca45026f -o br-e6c6ca45026f -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-db5f0b288d0b -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-db5f0b288d0b -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-db5f0b288d0b ! -o br-db5f0b288d0b -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-db5f0b288d0b -o br-db5f0b288d0b -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-e6c6ca45026f ! -o br-e6c6ca45026f -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-db5f0b288d0b ! -o br-db5f0b288d0b -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-e6c6ca45026f -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-db5f0b288d0b -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN

(base) [liran@localhost ~]$ ifconfig
br-db5f0b288d0b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:b1:a2:5c:1e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-e6c6ca45026f: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        ether 02:42:30:14:c7:09  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:de:2b:44:03  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp7s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f8:75:a4:31:51:b1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10  bytes 390 (390.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 390 (390.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.172.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.172.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 69  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.102.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.102.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 70  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a00:a040:199:d001::1000  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::245:9de5:cdb8:4e8b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a00:a040:199:d001:110d:97b0:26a6:ef1e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 4c:1d:96:05:98:1c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15060  bytes 15676416 (14.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5081  bytes 1244776 (1.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
(base) [liran@localhost ~]$ which pip
~/anaconda3_2020_11/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't figure out yet why is pip install doesn't connect with the server, but I managed to install the specific packages I wanted (django, djangorestframework) using `conda install django` and `conda install -c conda-forge djangorestframework`